# Packaging Angular 2 app for distribution to a production iis server

Tags: angular, npm

I've been going through the Angular 2 tutorial and have successfully got everything to work as expected, However the tutorial does not go into packaging for production distribution.  Surely there must be a standard way of creating a clean distribution package that doesn't include all the typescript files and any unnecessary dependencies.

I've searched the web, but can see no official way of doing this. Can I use NPM to do this, and if so can someone explain it? I come from a .net background so am used to clicking publish in vs2013 and it all being dandy for me :-)

Comment: Assuming you're using the angular CLI, have you done "ng build -prod" ? It will output your distribution bits to "dist". All I do is copy them over to the server (assuming your base href is set properly) and all works fine.

Comment: Note I also use straight Webpack and ES6 for angular 2 as well, and all I have to do is configure webpack.config the way I want (look on the webpack site) and run webpack --progress (with any switches I want), and all is well.

Comment: Ive just followed the tutorial.  It never mentions angular CLI.

Comment: If you're using TypeScript, I recommend it. It's not required at all (I personally am moving away from TS in favor of straight ES6), but the Angular CLI is a great tool. 

You probably mean "Tour of Heroes". That won't get you up and running for production (though it is a great tutorial for TS folk). The Webpack site also has a lot of info. If you don't want to use the CLI, I'd recommend it (the CLI actually uses Webpack). I wrote a bit on this, take a look at my website, www.tcoz.com, go to "errata" and find the Angular 2, ES6, Webpack, Babel article. I've got a seed project on github, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you are using the [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). In this case, you can easily create a build for production with `ng build --prod`.

See the accordant part about [Build Targets and Environment Files](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#creating-a-build).

If you are not using the Angular-CLI, take a look at [Installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation) and [Usage](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#usage). Or take a look at [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli). It is worth it.

Comment: It's ng build -prod (one hyphen)?

Oddly, the CLI wiki shows no hyphen at all. I'm betting that's a typo?

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: Actually now I'm really confused. I cloned the wiki and found this:

All builds make use of bundling, and using the `--prod` flag in  `ng build --prod`
or `ng serve --prod` will also make use of uglifying and tree-shaking functionality. I'm going to bet the -- is correct.

Comment: I tried all three, it seems both -prod and --prod do the same thing. Just plain "prod" (like it shows in the CLI wiki doc) seems to get ignored there's no error etc.

Comment: @TimConsolazio Overall: did it work and is everything fine, or do you need more help?

Comment: I didn't post the question; I've always been just fine using -prod. I did post it as an issue on the CLI git repo, and got a response that "--prod is the standard, -prod works but IMHO shouldn't, prod doesn't work and that's correct" (the docs do not make this clear though, in fact they suggest "prod" would work). Although "prod" should probably throw some kind of "unknown switch, did you mean --prod" or something.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for that. However, it is always interesting to read further details :)